# REGEX para prefijos y sufijos cuando \b no reconoce caracteres españoles (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Aclarar que estoy trabajando con las limitaciones que tiene en cuanto a regex el lenguaje **Javascript**.

Necesito realizar una búsqueda regex de una palabra que puede contener (o no) prefijos (**mega**,**super**) y sufijos (**ita**,**aza**). La palabra será una variable que, si por ejemplo valiera **cas**, la búsqueda quedaría así:

```
(mega|super)?cas(ita|aza)?[a-u]?
```

En la práctica no habrá dos prefijos y dos sufijos, serán unos treinta antes y treinta después pero, para el ejemplo, he elegidos dos y dos. De forma que si encontrase el siguiente texto, debería devolver tres resultados:

```
"Yo tenía una supercasita que se transformó en casa y acabó siendo una megacasaza."
```

Match 1  `supercasita`
Match 2  `casa`
Match 3  `megacasaza`

Pero si el texto fuese el siguiente, no debería hallar coindencia alguna:

```
"Yo tenía unasupercasita que se transformó en casay acabó siendo una megacasaza."
```

Ni tampoco debería encontrar nada en este caso:

```
"Yo tenía usupercasitana que se transcasaformó en y acabó siendo umegacasazana."
```

Sin embargo, sí debería encontrar las palabras en este otro texto:

```
"Yo tenía una (supercasita) que se transformó en:casa y acabó siendo una...megacasaza."
```

Sé que esto se solucionaría añadiendo al principio y al final de la regex lo siguiente:

```
\b(mega|super)?cas(ita|aza)?[a-u]?\b
```

Pero no puedo usar `\b` porque ciertas letras de nuestro alfabeto no las considera palabras, por ejemplo, si en base a la regex inmediatamente anterior tengo esto:

```
"Yo comprésupercasita que se transformócasa y acabómegacasaza."
```

Y seleccionaría esto:

Match 1 `supercasita`
Match 2 `casa`
Match 3 `megacasaza`

Cuando no debería seleccionar ninguna.

Una vez expuesto el problema, estas son mis cuestiones:

1. Si tengo 30 prefijos y sufijos, ¿Cómo hago para no tener que utilizar `?:` en cada opción y por lo tanto evitar su captura, ya que solamente me interesa la captura global?
2. Y la pregunta más difícil e importante, ¿Cómo simulo el comportamiento de `\b` para los casos de caracteres no contemplados como àäéëíïóöúüñç y más caracteres que existen en otros idiomas y seguramente no contempla `\b`

Comment: He de decir que para el comportamiento posterior de `\b` creo poder sustituirlo por:  

(?=[\s\;\:\)\(\]\[\.\}\{\?\¿\!\¡])  

Pero no sé hacer lo mismo por delante al no poder usar esta estructura `(?<=...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excelente pregunta. No tiene una respuesta que sea "absolutamente" igual que `\b`, pero se aproxima bastante.

#### Límites de palabra *aproximados* para español.

Para el límite previo a la palabra, como no estás utilizando el caracter previo a la palabra, podemos buscar que coincida con ese caracter, comprobando que sea el inicio del texto (`^`) o un `[^a-záéíóúüñ]`.

Para el límite posterior a la palabra, podemos verificar que no esté seguido por un caracter de palabra. Es decir `(?![a-záéíóúüñ])`.

Entonces, una palabra completa coincide sii:

```
/(?:^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])(palabra)(?![a-záéíóúüñ])/iu
```

- y si coincide, el resultado será capturado por el grupo 1 (así limpiamos el primer caracter que no nos interesa).
- esta es la única diferencia que tiene, que consume al caracter previo. Pero si no importa (como en este caso), va a coincidir como corresponde con todos los límites buscados.

> No incluí dígitos ni guión bajo, que quizás no te interesen en este caso, pero se pueden cambiar los `[a-záéíóúüñ]` por `[\d_a-záéíóúüñ]` si se quiere igualar el comportamiento de `\b`.

Llevado a tu ejemplo:

```
/(?:^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])((?:mega|super|ultra)?cas(?:ita|aza|ona|[aeiou])?(?![a-záéíóúüñ]))/igu
```

Demo:

```js
const ejemplos = [
        "Tres coincidencias: Yo tenía una supercasita que se transformó en casa y acabó siendo una megacasaza.",
        //La siguiente la modifiqué porque creo que estaba mal el ejemplo
        "Ninguna: Yo tenía unasupercasita que se transformó en casay acabó siendo una megacasazaa.",
        "Sí en: Yo tenía una (supercasita) que se transformó en:casa y acabó siendo una...megacasaza."
      ],
      regex = /(?:^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])((?:mega|super|ultra)?cas(?:ita|aza|ona|[aeiou])?(?![a-záéíóúüñ]))/igu;
      
var match, palabra;

for (let ej of ejemplos) {
    console.log('FRASE:', ej);
    while (match = regex.exec(ej)) {

        // Acá obtenemos el texto capturado por el primer grupo
        palabra = match[1];

        console.log('Palabra:', palabra);
    }
}
```

**Para `replace()`**. Hay algunos casos donde sí importa cómo tratamos al caracter previo. Por ejemplo, si queremos poner en negritas a las palabras, tenemos que capturar al caracter previo (`$1` será el caracter previo y `$2` la palabra).

```
regex = /(^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])((?:mega|super|ultra)?cas(?:ita|aza|ona|[aeiou])?(?![a-záéíóúüñ]))/igu;
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//   grupo con captura en vez de (?:  )

enNegritas = texto.replace( regex, '$1<b>$2</b>');
```

Y para otros casos, serán opciones similares, adaptando este tipo de lógica.

#### Alternativas

1. Podrías utilizar la librería [**XRegExp**](http://xregexp.com/) (de Steven Levithan), que tiene un excelente soporte de inspecciones hacia atrás (*lookbehinds*) y de Unicode, permitiendo usar [`\pL`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) (categoría Letra de Unicode). Se integra muy bien con los métodos que utilizamos habitalmente.

   ```js
   const re = XRegExp('(?<!\\pL)(?:mega|super|ultra)?cas(?:ita|aza|ona|[aeiou])?(?!\\pL)','igu'),
         texto = 'ácasa casañ megacasaza megasupercasona (casita)';
   console.log(texto);
         
   var match;

   while (match = re.exec(texto)) {
       console.log(match[0]);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
   ```

2. Chrome 62+ y Opera 49+ soportan inspecciones hacia atrás. Todavía es muy temprano para esperar que funcione en la mayoría de los navegadores, pero "funciona en mi PC" :-)

   ```js
   var regex;
   try {
       regex = new RegExp('(?<![a-záéíóúüñ])(?:mega|super|ultra)?cas(?:ita|aza|ona|[aeiou])?(?![a-záéíóúüñ])', 'igu');
   } catch (e) {
       throw new Error('Sólo funciona en Chrome 62+ y Opera 49+');
   }

   const texto = 'ácasa casañ megacasaza megasupercasona (casita)';
   console.log(texto);

   var match;

   while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
       console.log(match[0]);
   }
   ```

Comment: No respondí a la 1ra pregunta porque creo que te habías complicado con algo raro (suele suceder :-))... y creo que se sobreentiende viendo el regex en esta respuesta.

Comment: Como siempre, una respuesta inmejorable. No dejo de sorprenderme ante tu dominio con este tema de las regex. Adoptaré la primera solución que me ofreces. Mi intención es poner en negrita el texto que encuentre, así que tiene el problema de que si, antes de la palabra a buscar, existe un punto, un paréntesis o similar, también lo pondrá en negrita. Supongo que la solución sería recortar el array en su primer caracter si este coincide con alguno de los símbolos que podrían darse antes `.:,;([{/|¿¡` y alguno más que ahora se me pueda olvidar. Es sencillo. Un saludo y mil gracias @Mariano

Comment: @Pip no había considerado el reemplazo, pero no hace falta recortar a mano. Se puede usar un grupo para capturar el caracter previo. `texto.replace(/(^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])(palabra(?![a-záéíóúüñ]))/iu, '$1<b>$2</b>')`.

Comment: Perdona la tardanza en responder @Mariano, estaba realizando pruebas para varios casos. Cuando me has dicho esta última modificación para capturar un grupo extra con el espacio, sin leer hasta el final, ingenuo de mí pensé, claro, pero yo no necesito capturar el espacio en blanco, así que utilicé esto: `texto.replace(/((?:^|[^a-záéíóúüñ])(palabra(?![a-záéíóúüñ]))/iu, '<b>$1</b>')` Y después me di cuenta de que así estaba eliminando el espacio y se me juntaban las palabras. Al menos he llegado a la misma solución que me has dado en tu último comentario sin tener que volver aquí a mirarla.

Comment: @Pip en poco tiempo vas a estar respondiendo preguntas de [tag:regex] en el sitio

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano. Sin duda que lo haré, aunque no me sienta un experto en estas lides, pero no se me ocurre otra manera de pagar mi deuda contigo que ayudando a otros como tú lo has hecho conmigo. Un saludo.