# Expresión regular para palabras en php

Tags: php, regex

¿cómo están?
Estoy trabajando con preg_replace para sustituir cadenas, pero estoy atorado con una expresión regular. Yo tengo lo siguiente:

```
$texto = "Mi carro es dorado como el <b>carro</b> de enfrente";

preg_replace("/\bcarro[^\<]\b/", "auto",$texto);
```

Lo que quiero es que se reemplace solo la primera palabra carro, pero cuando tenga las etiquetas   no se reemplace la palabra.

El texto debería quedar así.

```
$texto = "Mi auto es dorado como el <b>carro</b> de enfrente";
```

Pero queda así, se come el espacio, debido a que la expresión regular dice que acepte todo excepto cuando tenga el símbolo < y es por eso que está borrando el espacio, pero no logro hacer la expresión regular, alguien tiene una idea?

```
$texto = "Mi autoes dorado como el <b>carro</b> de enfrente";
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar ['negative lookahead'](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (no se si hay una palabra en español):

```
/\bcarro(?!\<)\b/
```

https://regex101.com/r/3iybOe/1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Glorfindel, todo funciona muy bien, pero cuando tengo palabras que son por ejemplo éxito no lo reemplaza ni tampoco funciona con preg_match para encontrarla, tampoco funciona con palabras que tienen al final algún acento, pero sí con palabras que tienen acentos intermedios, tendrás una idea de por que sucede esto?

Comment: De nada. Desafortunadamente, `\b` [no soporta palabras con acentos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/143988/22845) entonces necesitarás construir tu propia versión :(